# Linking users in the comment

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I would like to link users in the comments. So far I did the back end (in Django) and now I'm struggling with the front end. I managed to write something with JavaScript to make usernames clickable when a comment has the character "@" in front of the name.

```
function urlify(texts) {
    var urlRegex = /(@[^\s]+)/g;
    return texts.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
      return '<a href="/profiles/' + url.substr(1) + '/">' + url + '</a>';
    })
}

var texts = $(".content1").text();

var html = urlify(texts);

$('.test1').prepend(html);
$('.content1').prepend(html);
```

Now I can get the first comment and make the usernames clickable.

How do I rewrite the code so every comment is replaced? I thought about a `for` loop but I'm not sure how to write it. Is there an easy way where I can replace all "@"s on the template with one function?

Comment: Where are the comments?  It's hard to say what to loop over, because you haven't shown any HTML examples.

Comment: [`$('.comment').each(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) ?? It's hard to say anything useful without some idea of the DOM structure that you are working on.

Comment: the comments are saved with the class "content1". 
Phix came up with a working solution but thanks for the tip with .each(function) will try this next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var string = 'Hey @user123, can you upload a file';
function urlify(texts) {
  var urlRegex = /(@[\w]+)/g;
  return string.replace(urlRegex, function(match){
    var name = match.slice(1);
    return '<a href="/users/profiles/' + name + '">' + match + '</a>'
  })
}

console.log(urlify(string));
```

Returns `Hey <a href="/users/profiles/user123">@user123</a>, can you upload a file`

Edit for multiple:

Using the string *Hey @user123, can you upload a file, otherwise @admin can you take a look*

Yields:

`Hey <a href="/users/profiles/user123">@user123</a>, can you upload a file, otherwise <a href="/users/profiles/admin">@admin</a> can you take a look`

...so no loop necessary.

Edit 2:

```
function urlify(texts) {
  var urlRegex = /(@[\w]+)/g;
  return texts.replace(urlRegex, function(match){
    var name = match.slice(1);
    return '<a href="/users/profiles/' + name + '">' + match + '</a>'
  })
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  var text = $('.comment').html(function(index, text) {
    return urlify(text)
  });
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/tehEF4ESYXf4TTRR5lz8?p=preview

Comment: i don't understand. i need a solution for 50 or 100 comments on the site, not one example string defined in the js. Your solution gives me the same result what i have in fact its almost the same code you just used slice(1) earlier... How do i replace !ALL! matches which have the class "content1".   
Thanks for the effort anyway. I hope i will find something

Comment: @Marla See update. Change classes and anything else you need to.

Comment: thanks a lot. Works like a charm. Sorry for not being specific in the first place...